# confirm con sweet alert

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en php, tengo un listado de personas donde al lado al un click donde se puede editar o eliminar el usuario, les comparto el codigo:

```
<td class='text-center'><a href='eliminar-personal.php?id_personal=<?php echo $crow['id_personal'];?> ' title="Eliminar Persona"><button type='button' class='fas fa-1x fa-trash-alt border-0' style='color:red;' onClick="return confirmar()"></button></a></td>
```

Resulta que quiero reemplazar el onClick="return confirmar()" por un sweet alert pero no hay caso no me funciona, no se porque sera.
Con javascript si funciona les comparto el codigo:

```
        function confirmar(){
    let respuesta = confirm("Esta seguro que desea eliminar esa persona??");
    if (respuesta == true){
    return true;
    }
    else{
    return false;
    }
    }
```

Alguien se le ocurre algo? porque no me toma el sweetalert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando ejecutas la función con el evento `onclick()`, podrías enviar como parámetro al `id_personal` que está en cada fila de tu tabla, sería de la siguiente forma:

```
<td class="text-center">
  <a onclick="eliminarPersona('<?php echo $crow['id_personal'] ?>')" title="Eliminar Persona"><button type="button" class="fas fa-1x fa-trash-alt border-0" style="color: red;"></button></a>
</td>
```

Y este parámetro sería enviado a tu función, en donde la función llama al `SweetAlert`. El `SweetAlert` esperará a que se confirme para que te redireccione al archivo donde se hace la consulta de eliminar, de lo contrario (si se cancela), el modal se cierra y no ocurre nada:

```
<script>
      // "persona" sería el "id_personal" de la fila que selecciones, y la función lo recibe
      function eliminarPersona(persona) {
      Swal.fire({
          title: "¿Eliminar personal?",
          text: "Procederás a eliminar al personal # " + persona + ", recuerda que... ¡Esto es irreversible!",
          icon: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
          cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
          confirmButtonText: "¡Sí, eliminar!",
          cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
      }).then((result) => {
          if (result.isConfirmed) { // si se confirma...
              // mostrará el siguiente mensaje...
              Swal.fire(
                  "¡Eliminado!",
                  "personal eliminado correctamente.",
                  "success"
              )
              // y posteriormente te mandará al archivo donde procede a eliminarlo.
              window.location.href = "eliminar-personal.php?id_personal=" + persona
          }
      });
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono perfecto.

Comment: @SidneyAlan-DesignerProgra buenas estimado, noté que quitó el verificado de mi respuesta, hubo algún inconveniente? si es así coméntanos =)

Comment: No, no, para nada, la tuya funciona perfecto. Gracias

Comment: Ok estimado, me alegro que le haya funcionado, saludos =)

Answer (score 1):

Yo le hice este cambio (`timer: '1000'`) que me parece que lo mejora, ya que antes se me redirigía muy rápido

```
Swal.fire({
            icon: "warning",
            title: "Eliminar",
            text: `¿Está seguro que desea eliminar el ?`,
            showCancelButton: true,
            cancelButtonColor: '#838383',
            confirmButtonColor: '#E2001A',
            confirmButtonText: 'Si, eliminalo',
            confirmButtonBorder: false,
            buttonsStyling: true,
            cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
            footer: "Si se elimina, no se podra recuperar el registro",
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: "¡Eliminado!",
                    text: "Registro eliminado correctamente.",
                    icon: "success",
                    timer: '1000'
                }).then(value => {
                    window.location.href = "eliminar-personal.php?id_personal=" + persona
                });
            } 
        })
```