# Mostrar una alerta cuando se elimine un registro

Tags: javascript, php

tengo un CRUD en PHP y MySQL, lo que quiero es que al pulsar el botón de eliminar un registro, me aparezca una advertencia de esta seguro (esta parte lo hace bien) y después de que confirmes que te aparezca el registro ha sido eliminado. Esto también lo hace, pero el problema llega cuando recargar, porque estoy enviando una variable por URL y siempre que recargas te vuelve a aparecer la alerta.

**Formulario HTML**

```
<form action="eliminar.php" method='POST' name="formu" class="formulario-eliminar">
     <input value="<?php echo $aire['id']?>" name="txtId" type="hidden"/>
     <input value="<?php echo $page?>" name="page" type="hidden"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Eliminar" name="btnEliminar" class="del input" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

Se sube el registro a la base de datos y te lo redirige con un parametro en la URL

```
header("location: aire.php?page=$page&Eliminado=true");
```

**Pagina de exito PHP**

Despues tengo otra pagina con HTML, que tiene un codigo de PHP para mostrar la alerta, la muestra bien, pero al recargar se vuelve a mostrar.

```
if(isset($_GET["eliminado"]) && $_GET["eliminado"] == true)
    {
        ?>
            <script>
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: 'El registro se ha eliminado correctamente',
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#E2001A',
                    timer: 15000,
                })
            </script>
        <?php
        $_SESSION['eliminado'] = false;
    }
```

¿Cómo se solucionaría? Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Esta respuesta quizás sea de tu ayuda https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/570320/confirm-con-sweet-alert/570330#570330

Comment: @Cris223511.dev El link que me pasaste tiene un problema y es cuando llama a la alerta de confirmación no me la muestra bien, porque de una te redirige para eliminarlo.

Comment: Claro, te redirige cuando vas a confirmar, si cancelas no elimina.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev  Le hice algunos cambios a lo que me mostraste y ya me funciona. La cosa era que te redirigía muy rápido, entonces puse que te redirigiera después de que saliera la alera con un .then y a la alerta le puse un timer

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Gracias!